# Инвертировать бит

Tags: c++, c, битовые-операции

Как инвертировать один бит в целом числе?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Коли уж вопрос с тегом [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), то ответ соответствующий: использовать `std::bitset` и функцию-член [`flip`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/flip/):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::bitset<8> v(123);
    std::cout << v << "\n";
    v.flip(3);
    std::cout << v << "\n"; 
}
```

<kbd>[Посмотреть результат](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4Di7FxyrlEhw9Ksq)</kbd>

Answer (score 14):

C помощью xor с соответствующей маской.

Например, чтобы инвертировать 3-й бит в числе x

```
unsigned int x = .....;
unsigned int mask = (1 << 3);
x ^= mask;
```